# Php mysql process table, with fast filling

Tags: php, mysql, gearman

i have a question:

I have a table like this one(just an example)

```
table:
id int auto_increment
user_id int,
ts timestamp,
type int,
```

and some other data, every second a lot of data inserted.

i have a [gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php) task to do some work with this data.(code example below)

```
<?php
     while(true) {
         // this method removs all data older than 1 day
         clear_old_data() 
         //fetches data with ts(timestamp) not older than 15 minutes
         //here is sql
         //type = 2 = data which i need to select
         $SQL = 'SELECT * FROM my_table where type = 2 and ts < unix_timestamp() - 15';
         $data = get_data_from_table($SQL);
         //than i am doing fetch each row and processing data
         while ($row = $data->fetchRow(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
             //do some stuff here
            // and set type to 4(processed)
         }

     }
     ....
?>
```

code is fast, i tested id with `microtime` each iteration(9000 rows) for 2 minute or so.

**My problem is** : that a lot of data inserted every second and this speed is not enough to process rows fast.
I need to find a solution to run this code in parallel mode or 2-3-4-5-... instances of this code.
but i dont have a clue where to look and what to do, i am stuck.

maybe i need to change my sql( to run it in parallel mode).

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where type = 2 and ts < unix_timestamp() - 15
```

I would be grateful for any advice

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks, posted on reddit, [link](http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/35tmu4/php_mysql_process_table_with_fast_filling/)

Comment: You should better set some triggers, events, stored procedures on MySQL side not on php side. `clear_old_data()` I am absolutely sure this job should be run as event on MySQL and it would be ten times faster and efficient.

Comment: @Alex `clear_old_data()` is fast

Comment: even if it is fast - it is wrong place  to put, and bad practice to `while(true)`